# Brackets.io error opening file, "Brackets currently only supports UTF-8 encoded text files"

Tags: html, adobe-brackets

I was working on my index.html, a lot of work was going on. So the next day when I went to open it up. I get this message, screenshot below.

I don't know why this happened

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What platform are you on? You can probably load the file into Notepad (if you are on Windows) and re-save it in UTF-8 using the Save dialogue box.

Comment: When i open  it in notepad++  i get Nul  Nul Nul Nul Nul Nul Nul Nul Nul